# pandas exponentially slower when running concurrently in multiple processes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I have a method that uses pandas to do extensive read-only calculations on a 800MB DataFrame loaded using read_pickle.

The method takes approx 500ms of CPU time to execute. Let's call this method search_with_pandas.

I saved this method in a module I'll call "search_with_pandas_module", it looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# load 800MB dataframe
core = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\test\core.bz2")

def search_with_pandas(inputs):
    scores = core[core.input.isin(inputs)].groupby(["item_id"]).item_id.count().sort_values(ascending=False)
    return scores
```

Multiple users need to access this method so I went about parallelizing the code with multiple processes.
I have a 12 core machine, and I'm starting 10 processes, like so:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    PORT_START = 12000
    cpu_count = 10
    for x in range(cpu_count):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=(PORT_START+x,))
        proc.start()
```

Each of the 10 worker processes exposes a simple WSGI interface, each on it's own port. This means each process stays alive, waiting for requests.

```
def worker(port):
    from bottle import route, run, request
    from time import time

    import search_with_pandas_module

    @route('/search',method='GET')
    def search():
        time_start = time()
        response = search_with_pandas_module.search_with_pandas()
        # this returns in 500ms when run from one process at a time
        print "time took:", time()-time_start

        return response        

    run(host="127.0.0.1",port=port)
```

Each worker process imports the search_with_pandas_module when it starts, which means each worker process has it's own copy of the 800MB DataFrame used by the search_with_pandas method. There is no IPC/synchronization overhead to deal with between processes because each worker has it's own independent copy.

I now have 10 processes, on 10 different ports, each addressable by:

- http://127.0.0.1:12000/search
- http://127.0.0.1:12001/search
- http://127.0.0.1:12002/search  etc...

Now the strange part. If I use one process at a time, the search_with_pandas method takes 500ms as expected. However, when I access these concurrently the search_with_pandas method starts getting slower and slower, even though each call is handled by an independent process.

- no concurrency: 500ms
- 2 concurrent calls: 684 ms
- 3 concurrent calls: 959 ms
- 4 concurrent calls: 988 ms
- 5 concurrent calls: 1193 ms
- 6 concurrent calls: 1423 ms
- 7 concurrent calls: 1567 ms
- 8 concurrent calls: 1812 ms
- 9 concurrent calls: 2096 ms
- 10 concurrent calls: 2253 ms

[Here is a screenshot of my CPU graph while running these tests, please note that with more concurrency you can see more CPU utilization as each worker operates concurrently.](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/6011b5993c3a866459040b6b8094e7304210dbd1/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f49545550754d452e706e67)

I can't figure out why the method is taking exponentially longer to execute when running concurrently.

It's almost as if pandas is locking something internally that is forcing the other processes to wait until released.

Building/tearing down each process is a non-issue because each process starts only once and stays alive.

Each process has it's own independent copy of the 800MB dataframe so why would a CPU intensize read-only operation on one process make other processes slower?

I"m running Windows 7 64bit, 24GB RAM, SSD drives

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Excessive page swapping might be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but RAM isn't the issue, I have 24 gigs.  I"m never above 50-60% memory usage.

Comment: Have you looked at `dask` with a stored dataframe, then just interfacing with a worker process from a single bottle app?

Comment: Also - since you're `import`ing within the worker - you're loading it each time from disk - so if you're doing that quickly across multiple workers - they'll all be trying to load the same file which'll be a bit of a bottle neck - you might be better off just loading it outside the function and so it's in a global context for the app and not the worker function.

Comment: The workers only load the large file once, when each worker first starts up.  I defintely see the IO spike when the workers first start, which is expected, they're all reading the large file into their memory.

Comment: I haven't looked into dask, but i will now